# Text align in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, alignment, grid-layout

I've got GridLayout-JPanel. In every cell there is a JLabel with some String. How can I right-align this text in my cells?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple `JLabel` constructors take horizontal alignment arguments. These [constants](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingConstants.html) are inherited from `SwingConstants`.

Comment: Yes, thats right. But let's say I've got 100 JLabels. When I right-align them with constructor, and decide change that to left-align, I'll have to do it one hundred times by hand. Is there a way, to align them all with one move from layout manager level?

Comment: If you're unwilling to encapsulate such logic, use the [`setAlignmentY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#setAlignmentY%28float%29) method. That is how a container can set the horizontal alignment of any `JComponent` instance (e.g. a `JLabel`).

Comment: @Noran you can create class or void with parameters that returns JLabel, you can use SwingConstant, JLabel#possition, or by using Html <=3.2 +1

Answer (score 23):

@Noran In response to your comment on @mre's answer, you could initialize all the JLabels into an array. Then, all you'd have to do is loop through the array and set the alignment that way.

```
for (JLabel label: arrayOfJLabels) {
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
}
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

I have read your question and I have a suggestion.  There are a few methods to fulfill your requirement.  Since you didn't mention the exact requirement, I can give you a simple example as I understand it:

```
//create a JLabel and name it as jLabel2
javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
jLabel2.setText("Dehans Label");
jLabel2.setHorizontalTextPosition(javax.swing.SwingConstants.RIGHT);
```

Please refer following methods @ `JLabel` class in JavaSE API through following links:

- [public void setHorizontalAlignment(int alignment)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setHorizontalAlignment%28int%29)
- [public void
  setVerticalAlignment(int alignment)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setVerticalAlignment%28int%29)
- [public void
  setVerticalTextPosition(int textPosition)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JLabel.html#setVerticalTextPosition%28int%29)

Comment: It is best to link to the latest version of the JavaDocs. I have edited your answer to point to J2SE 7. For tips on getting a link to the latest docs, see [point 2 of advantages](http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7090875).